# How do I properly use sizeof to measure the block to malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, sizeof

Assume I have a simple struct, including some pointers:

```
typedef struct Type {
    uint32_t* intArrayPointer;
} Type;
```

What is the correct way, to malloc the struct pointer? As both ways work, I assume one of the two does allocate more memory than needed:

1. ```
    Type* newType() {
        Type* returnPointer = malloc(sizeof(Type));
        returnPointer->intArrayPointer = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*128);
        return returnPointer;
    }
   ```
2. ```
    Type* newType() {
        Type* returnPointer = malloc(sizeof(Type*));
        returnPointer->intArrayPointer = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*128);
        return returnPointer;
    }
   ```

For reference, how this would be used in Code:

```
void freeType(Type* this) {
    free(this->intArrayPointer);
    free(this);
}

int main() {
    Type* pt = newType();
    //do Stuff
    freeType(pt);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(Type*)` could be bigger, smaller, or equal to `sizeof(Type)`. The crucial point is that it is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way would be to use

```
Type* returnPointer = malloc(sizeof(*returnPointer));
```

or, better,

```
Type* returnPointer = malloc(sizeof *returnPointer); 
            // parenthesis is needed only when argument is a type, 
            // not needed for expressions used as argument
```

which does not depend on the type at all.

Same way, you should do for `intArrayPointer`, too. And don't forget to check for the success of the calls, too.

Comment: With the `intArrayPointer` I really do want to reserve 512 contiguous Bytes, with the pointer pointing to the first one.

Comment: @WhozCraig very valid, let me add that.

Comment: @FrankPirata That's OK, I'm only talking about the syntax.

Comment: Minor: `sizeof *returnPointer` with the space, looks less like a multiplication than `sizeof*returnPointer`.